# How is the current density derived?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I would like to know how the formula $J= \sigma  E$

Our teacher said that all of the books never really explained how they found the question, so I assumed someone here knows the equation.

Answer (score 2):

This is really Ohm's law. It is an empirical law, and therefore cannot be derived. In fact, it is sometimes not obeyed.

It came to be from observing current densities and the corresponding electric field, and noticing a linear relationship with some proportionality constant $\sigma$. However, in microscopic terms, $\sigma$ need not necessarily be constant, and can be a function of $\vec{E}$.

We can also view this as the Taylor series of $\vec{J}(\vec{E})$ in $\vec{E}$, truncated after the linear term.

Comment: Ohm's law can certainly be derived, by making certain assumptions. Starting from the completely wrong and obsolete Drude's model to the more complex Landauer's formula.

Comment: Well yes, what I meant was it can't be derived without making assumptions that are not always true, thus it is not always obeyed.

Comment: Ohm's law is not followed for semiconductors, HV breakdown, hot-filament light bulbs and lots of other non-ohmic materials. In short, Ohm's law is obeyed by all materials which obey Ohm's law. It's a beautiful tautological definition: Wittgenstein would approve.